# How to have Upstart redirect when Gunicorn crashes

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, upstart

I have a Django website deployed using gunicorn 0.17.0 that is launched by Upstart on Ubuntu 12.04 and uses nginx/1.1.19 for static media.
Sometimes when my django code has a bug, Gunicorn raises gunicorn.errors.HaltServer and keeps crashing and getting launched again and again. The way I find out is when I see the log quickly getting huge. And I have to stop the Gunicorn service manually. Then delete the huge log file. Debug and run it again.

My question is: What is the best way to approach this crashing and getting launched again? I know that launching automatically is the point of Upstart but in this case, it doesn't make sense to launch Gunicorn again when it crashes. 
Can Upstart stop launching Gunicorn when it raises this error? And then launch another service that redirects user to a different page on the website? What do you recommend?

Here is the Gunicorn log section that keeps getting repeated:
https://github.com/erasmose/kart/blob/master/kart/issues/kart_gunicorn_log.txt

Thanks,
Eras

Comment: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/252